# change TextView Text after Button click in android (OnClickListener)

Tags: android, textview

i m trying to make a function in which array will show on TextView and chnage the Text in TextView after onCLickListener()

can u please give Suggestion how can i change the Text in TextView after clicking on Button and do some Specific work in onCLickListener()

```html
 static int count;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
        {
     count=0;
     String[] qlist = { "Where is Captial of India", "Captial Of America"};
     TextView show_q =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     if(count <qlist.length){
     show_q.setText(qlist[count]);
     count= count+1;
     }
     else{
     // reset count here
     count=0;
     }
   }
        
});
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: what problem you are getting when doing as `show_q.setText("some test")` on Button click?

Comment: right now it is TextView is showing all the Text in Once 
but i want to change the Text after Clicking and Error in not showing in Error Log 
can u please tell me how i can achieve it  ?

Comment: see my answer probably help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am attaching a sample code using your code. Please use according to your requirements.

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String[] qlist = { "Where is Captial of India", "Captial Of America", "India Gate ", "Residence Eviel", "Chiti " };

                TextView show_q =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : qlist){
                builder.append(s+" ");
                show_q.setText(builder.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

If i understand your question wrong, Please comment.

Comment: @ Vivek
you are right,  but is there any way to display the Text in TextView one by one after clicking on Button in

Comment: You can make one global variable that will keep track of position of your array will start from 0. In each onClick first show the text from the array use that position. After setting the text increment the variable value by 1. Also check that your variable value should not exceed the array length-1. Hope it will help you. Any query please comment.

Comment: i surely upvote your Answers , please help me , i updated my code , but it is showing only first Value, suggestion will help me

Comment: Just to remove the line from the onClick. count=0; and write it before the onClick function. Thats it.

Comment: Cool Bro , you are great!  just one thing more, can u please tell me how to show first Value in TextView Before onClickListener()

Comment: Before onClick functionality use show_q.setText(qlist[0]). If you have any confusion. please comment.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i change the Text in TextView after clicking on Button:

Use an counter variable to get item from Array on every Button click:

```
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
    int count=0;
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(count <qlist.length)
              show_q.setText(qlist[count]);
                count++;
             }else{
                  // reset count here
                 count=0;
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is working for First Time but clicking on second Time TextView is not changing the Text,Please Help

Comment: how to show First Value always in TextView always ?

Comment: @AshuKumar : please post updated code with question to get more help

Comment: @AshuKumar: remove first `count=0;`  from onClick